# How to keep the '\n characters from a string?

Tags: python, web-scraping, extract

I am new to python and I'm trying to web scrape a website. However I'm having trouble doing getting \n\n\n in my output. I would get newlines in my output. I am using BeautifulSoup to scrap a page. My code is:

> print(soup.body.get_text())

Lets say that the text is:

> Hello, my name is: (second line is empty) (third line is empty) Charlie.

I want it to return:

> Hello, my name is:\n\nCharlie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'repr' function.

E.g:

```
print(repr(soup.body.get_text()))
```

It'll print the whole string including '\n'

Comment: This is a bad idea. This will turn newlines into `\n`. But it will also put quotes around the whole thing. And escape any backslashes and quotes in the string. And, depending on your Python version, it may also escape other perfectly nice characters with Unicode escape sequences.